# Seeking Whale Sighting Data

Tags: data-request, oceanographic, animals

### Summary

I have been seeking a data source (either API or downloadable data) that would contain information on whale sightings from around the world.

### Fields

Ideally it would contain all these fields but that is a long shot. I am looking for:

- species of whale
- timestamp of sighting
- location of sighting
- photo of sighting

### Other info

- It seems their used to be an open API [Whale Hotline](https://publicapis.io/the-whale-hotline-animals-api) that had a `/sightings` endpoint but the API is no longer active.
- The data I am after is similar to what is used on [happywhale.com](https://happywhale.com/) but I don't think their data is available to download.

If anyone knows of any data sources I could use I would be extremely grateful, thanks.